# Why is attachment file on email blank?

Tags: perl

My script sends email to a user with an attachment file.

The file name is *hello.txt*.
It contains **"HELLO WORLD!! :D"**.

When I send the email, the file *hello.txt* is attached with the email.
But, when I open the file, *hello.txt* is blank and empty.
It should contain **"HELLO WORLD!! :D"**

The CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;
$to = 'abc@gmail.com';
$from = 'abc@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Test Email';
$message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
   From => $from,
   To => $to,
   Cc => $cc,
   Subject => $subject,
   Type => 'multipart/mixed'                    #I SUSPECT, THE PROBLEM AT HERE
);
# Add your text message.
$msg->attach(
   Type => 'text',
   Data => $message
);
# Specify your file as attachement.
$msg->attach(Type => 'application/text',        #I SUSPECT, THE PROBLEM AT HERE
   Path => 'C:\Users\Desktop',
   Filename => 'hello.txt',
   Disposition => 'attachment'
);
$msg->send;
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

Should I change `Type` or `application/text`?

Comment: `application/text` is not a valid MIME type. Don't make up your own; use `text/plain` if that's what you mean, or `application/octet-stream` if you can't come up with a more specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Path => 'C:\Users\Desktop',
> ```

[Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#Path) should be the path name of the file on your system. What you gave is only the directory name, where the file is located. Trying to read this will result in empty data - and thus empty content for the attached file. Instead you need to use

> ```
> Path => 'C:\Users\Desktop\hello.txt',
> ```

Comment: Desktop looks uncommon here unless you have a user with that name.